# get image size before upload image php

Tags: php, file-upload

I want to know the image size in mb but before ulpload do the same.
I have:

```
$errors =       array();
$image =        $_FILES['image']['name'];
$file_tmp =     $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
$image_type =   $_FILES['image']['type'];
$descricao =    $_POST['descricao'];

if(empty($image) || $_FILES['image']['size'] >= 1000)
{
    $_SESSION['alert_type'] = -1;
    $_SESSION['msg_alert'] = "imagem didnt upload!";
}

else
{
 //upload
}
```

The problem is to know the file size, the $ _FILES ['image'] ['size'] is not working well.
thanks

Comment: what means *not working well*?

Comment: What result are you expecting and what are you getting? That should work but you're expecting the image to be less than a kilobyte which is a bit odd.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Before upload you can check like so:

```
$file_tmp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
$size = filesize($file_tmp);
```

But do you realize you are expecting the image to be less than a kilobyte in your code example?

Comment: seriously ?? All time I had in my mind, one cannot get the file size of file without uploading it or without using jqury.. thanks buddy !!

Comment: Yep, file uploads are really easy with PHP. If you have server side access no need for stuff like jquery unless you need interaction client side like progress bars, etc. For straight forward uploads everything you need is there :)

Answer (score 1):

Can't you use the function `filesize()?`

```
filesize($_FILES['image'])
```

or

```
filesize(//enter image url);
```

I would give you more details but the php.net site is having malware problems

Comment: i dont have image url. the user upload file then i need check image size. filesize($_FILES['image']) dont work:
"filesize() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path"

Comment: Use the tmp_name as in my answer above.

Comment: @pc_oc i see, use `filesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];`

Answer (score 1):

Well the plugin will help you :  [jQuery-File-Upload](http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/)

Answer (score 0):

Use php [`filesize`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php) function.You can get the bytes of the file

```
$imgsize = filesize( '/home/projects/site/1.jpg' );
```

Comment: i dont have save image, before save image i can check size

Comment: does $image contain file path ?

Comment: no, the user upload file then i need check image size to upload