# How I can store multiple attachment details like name, size, type, and content in database?

Tags: php, database

How can I store multiple attachment details like `name`, `size`, `type`, and `content` in a database? I have 8 file upload fields and just 4 columns in database `name`, `size`, `type`, and `content`.

Comment: You can first *try* using some php script (you should start with Google first maybe??).

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19564639/get-image-size-before-upload-image-php

Answer (score 0):

You can always use a `json_encode` function to convert the array into the string representative, also by using this you may also insert all the 8 file details in a single row.

```
$arr = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4, 'e' => 5);
echo json_encode($arr);
```

The output will be something like this 
`{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php - for referal